# Select specific dates in dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, date, datetime, subset

I have a dataframe `waterlevels` which consists of data from nine piezometers for the year 2021. The groundwater levels were measured each 15 minutes. This is the head of the df:

```
dateandtime abs_waterlevel_m well
2021-01-01 00:00:00         17.90863  K01
2021-01-01 00:15:00         17.90710  K01
2021-01-01 00:30:00         17.90445  K01
2021-01-01 00:45:00         17.90843  K01
2021-01-01 01:00:00         17.90751  K01
2021-01-01 01:15:00         17.90302  K01
```

So first the well K01, then comes well K02 and so on and this for the whole year of 2021. The datatype of the dateandtime variable is in POSIXct format.

I want to **select the rows corresponding to the first day of every month** so that I get the groundwaterlevels for all nine piezometers for the first day of the month at 00:00h. So the result should be a dataframe with 12 (months) x 9 (piezometers) = 108 rows.

I looked for hours on the internet finding a suggestion to do this, but I only found about data ranges and other dataformats, but I prefer to stick with POSIXct format - if possible.
For example, I used:

```
dates <- as.POSIXct(c("2021-01-01 00:00", "2021-02-01 00:00", "2021-03-01 00:00", "2021-04-01 00:00", "2021-05-01 00:00", "2021-06-01 00:00", "2021-07-01 00:00", "2021-08-01 00:00", "2021-09-01 00:00", "2021-10-01 00:00", "2021-11-01 00:00", "2021-12-01 00:00"))
selection <- waterlevels[as.POSIXct(waterlevels$dateandtime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') %in% dates]
```

But then I got the error that undefined columns are selected, but I don't understand why.

So how can I solve this issue?

Comment: can you `dput()` some of your data as a reproducible example please?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)
testdata[day(testdata$dateandtime) == 01,]
```

Does that work for you?

Edit adding in time of day as requested (albeit a bit clumsily, sorry!)

```
testdata[day(testdata$dateandtime) == 01 &
           hour(testdata$dateandtime) == 0 &
           minute(testdata$dateandtime) == 0 &
           second(testdata$dateandtime) == 0,]
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, but only the day but I still got the all the times of the day (hours and minutes - each 15 minutes). But it's OK, I took the average groundwater level per day, then I applied your command and that works! So thank you!

Comment: MY apologies, I missed the requirement for 00:00